# Read src attribute from a text field with pasted iFrame code inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a form where a person can past the iframe code into the field.

When I read that field I want to extract just the src of the iFrame, not the entire iFrame code.

I know how to read the full value of the input but I do not know how to extract just the src.

How do I do this?

I am using jQuery 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/476/

HTML:

```
<input class="temp" type="text" value='<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>' />
```

JS:

```
var a = $('.temp').val();
var src =  $(a).attr('src'); // $(a).attr('src') will give you the src
```

**Note**: This will work provided the iframe code in the input is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to extract the src attribute of your iframe:

```
var text = '<iframe src="http://...."></iframe>';
var regex = /src="([^"]+)"/;

console.log(regex.test(text)); //returns true if a match was found
console.log(regex.exec(text)); //returns the matched results.
```